# AdMob not initialized from flutter notification

Tags: android, flutter, dart, notifications, admob

So I have a very simple application.
In Main I initialize Admob and call Root Widget.
From Root I show a Stateful Widget "Home".
From Home Call the Notification Logic.
When you "click" on the notification I send you again to Root.

When I first run the application, the adMobBanner works good.
After you receive the notification and you click on it, the app starts again, everything works as expected but the adMobBanner is a black banner now.

I think the Admob is not initialized properly. I tried to "Admob.initialize("appId")" in Root, in LocalNotification widget, everywhere, but still the same result.

Any ideas?

```
void main() async {
  Admob.initialize("appId");
  runApp(Root());
}

class Root extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title = "Title";
  Root();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: title,
        ),
        home: Home(title: title));
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  Home({this.title});

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final adMobBanner = AdmobBanner(adUnitId: "id", adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(),
          adMobBanner,
          LocalNotification()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LocalNotification extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocalNotificationState createState() => _LocalNotificationState();
}

class _LocalNotificationState extends State<LocalNotification> {

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //initialization notification plugin
    showNotification(); //the notification with onSelectNotification callback
  }

  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return Root(); // send you to Root again
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: I found a temporary solution. Instead of Navigator.Push in the onSelectNotification 
I will just runApp(Root()); again.

Comment: I recommend you to use the official plugin for Flutter: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob